# append to pickle file [python opencv face recognition]

Tags: python, pickle

I would like to combine two pickle files into a new onethat both come from face recognition. I have a main actors.pkl file that one holds a lot of actors, now I would like to update this file but not using the imageset update methode. So I am creating a new picklefile actorupdate.pkl in this set are the registered faces not in actors.pkl

I am able to open / read both files and they both work perfect (recognition wise) so how would I be able to join both files into a new one (or append actorupdate.pkl to actors.pkl)

```
import pickle

data = pickle.loads(open("encodings/actors.pkl", "rb").read())
data2 = pickle.loads(open("encodings/actorupdate.pkl", "rb").read())

verify dataset (names):
data['names'] = ['ben_afflek', 'ben_afflek', 'ben_afflek', 'ben_afflek', 'ben_afflek', 'ben_afflek', 'ben_afflek', 'ben_afflek', ........
data2['names'] = ['Gal_Gadot', 'Gal_Gadot', 'Gal_Gadot', 'Gal_Gadot', 'Gal_Gadot', 'Gal_Gadot']
```

trying to use this methode:

```
filename="picklefile"
with open(filename, 'wb') as fp:
   pickle.dump(data ,fp)
   pickle.dump(data2 ,fp)
```

but in that case it writes a new file to my disk but the information from data2 is not there, it became just a copy of data and I would like to use the file directly not create a new pickle file on my disk.

Answer (score 1):

I found the following worked (had to loop over the contents of the data2):

```
data1 = pickle.load(open('encodings/actors.pkl', 'rb'))
data2 = pickle.loads(open("encodings/actorupdate.pkl", "rb").read())

new_encodings = data1['encodings']
new_names = data1['names']

for encode in data2['encodings']:
    new_encodings.append(encode)

for name in data2['names']:
    new_names.append(name)

data = {"encodings": new_encodings, "names": new_names}
with open(data1 , 'wb') as fp:
    pickle.dump(data, fp)
```

data now holds both pickle files and allows to detect the faces from both pickle files, the file data1 itself is overwritten with the updated dataset (data2) on disk.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply append second list into first one and then just dumps it

Comment: actually that makes two groups ['ben_aflek', 'ben_aflek'....]['gal_gadot'...] and the face recognition only works on the first group.

Comment: You are taking it wrong . You are appending the complete data2 list to first one thats why it is showing two groups
What i was trying to say is iterate the data2 list using for loop and for each element in data2  append it to data1.
Then you will get both the list in single group